# An Island Getaway

Tags: visual, geography

My friend Pat is a travel agent, and each year we like to go to an island we've never been to before. Being a bit puzzling, Pat doesn't tell me our destination directly, but instead sends me a weird picture. I never know where the heck I'm going which makes it really hard to pack. Two years ago, Pat sent me this picture:

[image: Trip 1]

We ended up in Martha's Vineyard. Last year, Pat sent me this picture:

[image: Trip 2]

Our trip was to The Hamptons that year.

This year is a big birthday for me, so Pat is planning something special. But all I get is this image:

[image: Trip 3]

Can you please help me figure out where I'm headed?

Solver Notes: For the color-blind...I am sorry. This puzzle pretty much requires analysis of the colors and shapes in the images.

HINT #1:

> I just remembered that Pat arranged our trip three years ago too. We went to Rum Cay in the Bahamas, and I got this picture. It looks pretty similar to the others, I guess: [image: Trip 0]

HINT #2:

> The identifications provided by @MrSethward are correct, but there is another step to determine the trip destination, which is not in North Carolina. As a hint, the order of the icons in the pictures matters.

HINT #3:

> Google's My Maps provides a useful function that the usual Google Maps does not that can help you solve this puzzle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like Pat is taking you to:

> the Ile de Sein, a Breton island off the coast of western France.

The images represent:

> lighthouse designs. At humn's request, as I was looking at the images in the OP, I was checking for any patterns that might be a foothold. The blue background got me thinking it was sea and when I noticed the towers on each had different shapes as well as colors, I realized it might be physical clues related to the island, and lighthouses just popped out as the most obvious solution to search. I wasn't totally sure I was on the right track, as til now haven't nailed down the first two clues but when I found the lighthouses in the Outer Banks, I once I found the Outer Banks lighthouses I was certain.

With that you:

> draw lines between the lighthouses, the next land encountered is the island you are visiting!

The image for Martha's Vineyard represent:

> #1 [Oak Island](https://asset---north-carolina.bldg15.net/img/a/3/a3e5561d-9716-469f-9704-8705b47c5105/Oak_Island_Lighthouse_VisitNC.1f59ef16.jpg)

> #2 [Currituck Beach light](https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-m/1280/1b/27/4b/63/closer.jpg)

The images for The Hamptons are:

> #1 [Ocracoke lighthouse](https://www.nps.gov/caha/planyourvisit/images/IMG_2927.jpg?maxwidth=650&autorotate=false)

> #2 [Bodie Island lighthouse](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/Bodie_Island_Lighthouse%2C_July_2007.jpg/1200px-Bodie_Island_Lighthouse%2C_July_2007.jpg)

Their connections are:

> The lines to Martha's vineyard and the Hamptons:
>  [image]

And the final image:

> I'm much more sure of these than the previous ones, I think #1 is [Cape Lookout lighthouse](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Cape_Lookout_Lighthouse.jpg/1200px-Cape_Lookout_Lighthouse.jpg) and #2 is the [Cape Hatteras lighthouse](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/Cape_hatteras_lighthouse_img_0529.jpg/440px-Cape_hatteras_lighthouse_img_0529.jpg), both in the Outer Banks in North Carolina.
>  
> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: rot13(Lbh unir gur yvtugubhfr vqrn pbeerpg, ohg lbh'ir zvfvqragvsvrq gur yvtugubhfrf va gur svefg gjb gevcf. Gubhtu V nqzvg gur Tnl Urnq bar vf n pybfr zngpu gb gur vagraqrq. V erpbzzraq hfvat gur vasbezngvba nobhg gur gjb lbh'ir pbeerpgyl vqragvsvrq gb frr vs gurer ner orggre zngpurf.)

Comment: rot13(V jnf jbaqrevat vs Sver Vfynaq zvtug'ir orra obgu orpnhfr jnf bevtvanyyl (juvgr/perzr) orsber orvat fgevcrq, ohg gur urvtug qvssrerapr znqr zr punatr gur nafjre. Jvyy xrrc ybbxvat sbe obgu.)

Comment: Let me give you a quick nudge. rot13(Abar bs gur yvtugubhfrf vf va rvgure Arj Lbex be Znffnpuhfrggf.)

Comment: Not sure if you're planning on doing more, but as of 06-26-20 midnight Zulu this is not the correct answer. You are on the right track, though.

Comment: ^vote with 2 notes, @MrSethward: 1) I hope you don't mind that i added a picture from the links in your solution. The visual connection is amazing. 2) Any chance of mentioning in your solution how that connection occurred to you?

Comment: One other note: there is nothing historical represented here. Everything represented exists as it is today.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, sorry, UK time so was sleeping but working on it more today! Hope to solve it.

Comment: Thanks @humn, that's fantastic, wasn't sure if it would work with the spoilers to have images, this is much nicer!

Comment: No worries. I just didn't want to waste your time chasing down increasingly less likely explanations. You're definitely closer to home, or maybe given the topic...further from home :-) One more quick nudge: check out the tags on the puzzle.

Comment: @JeremyDover I have an idea.. rot13(ner lbh tbvat gb fbzrjurer va Zrkvpb?)

Comment: @DanielC.: not on this trip

Comment: Hi @MrSethward! Just wanted to send a ping that I've added a couple of hints that can hopefully get you where you need to be. You're so close!

Comment: Hey @Jeremy Dover, was just checking out! Heading outside for a bit before I updated, but is it based on rot13(Fgenvtug yvar qvfgnapr orgjrra gur yvtugubhfrf naq gur arkg ynaq rapbhagrerq? Arrq gb purpx pnershyyl, ohg V guvax vg ynaqf ba gur Vfyrf bs Fpvyyl!)

Comment: rot13(Znxr fher lbh'er hfvat terng pvepyrf). I think you might be off by about 35 leagues, but you are very close!

Comment: Alright @JeremyDover, I hope I've got it. Thanks for this, great puzzle!

Comment: YES! Excellent job, and thanks for sticking to it! I am glad you enjoyed!